# Change axis label automatically when y parameter is changed in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2020, 2021, 2022),
                 height = c(21, 25, 29),
                 weight = c(10, 12, 15))
```

I want to plot year vs. height/ weight using ggplot2. To that end, I wrote a function like so:

```
plot <- function(dataframe,  xvalue, yvalue) {
  ggplot(dataframe)+
    geom_line(aes(x = xvalue, y = yvalue))+
    #ylab = some code that automatically changes this label based on yvalue
}
```

For example:

`plot(df, df$date, df$height)`, the y-axis is automatically labeled as "height"

[image]

`plot(df, df$date, df$weight)`, the y-axis is automatically labeled as "weight"

[image]

I hope I was able to explain the problem.

Comment: If you don't do anything, `ggplot` will automatically label the axis for you based on the variable name. Unless you want to make the axis label look nicer?

Comment: Yes, I want to make it look nicer; say I want to add units in brackets in my labels. For eg. Height (inches) or Weight (pounds).

Answer (score 0):

Your function could be:

```r
my_plot <- function(dataframe,  xvalue, yvalue) {
  ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = {{xvalue}}, y = {{yvalue}})) +
    geom_line() 
}
```

Which allows:

```r
plot(df, year, height)
```

[image]

Or, based on your comments,

```r
plot <- function(dataframe,  xvalue, yvalue, xlab, ylab) {
  ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = {{xvalue}}, y = {{yvalue}})) +
    geom_line() +
    xlab(xlab) +
    ylab(ylab)
}
```

Which allows:

```r
plot(df, year, height, 'Year', 'Height (in inches)')
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `ylab(deparse(substitute(yvalue)))` to avoid repeating the y input. But not so simple for a fancy label.

Comment: @Peter but the OP wanted the freedom to change the axis titles, and there is no need to use `deparse(substitute` if you are keeping the labels as they are - this is the default behaviour - see the first example.

Comment: I see that's changed from the original post: "the y-axis is automatically labeled as "height". Fair dos

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do: create two lists (1) variable names, (2) variable labels then loop through them

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(year = c(2020, 2021, 2022),
                 height = c(21, 25, 29),
                 weight = c(10, 12, 15))
# var name
y_var <- colnames(df[colnames(df) != "year"])
# var label
y_label <- c("Height (feet)", "Weight (lbs)")

# plot function
time_plot <- function(DF,  x_var, y_var, x_lab, y_lab) {
  plt <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = .data[[x_var]], y = .data[[y_var]])) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = x_lab,
         y = y_lab) +
    theme_classic(base_size = 14)
  
  return(plt)
}

# loop using `map2`
plt_list <- map2(y_var, y_label, 
                 ~ time_plot(df,  "year", .x, "Year", .y))
plt_list[[1]]
```

[image]

```r
plt_list[[2]]
```

[image]

```r
# combine all plots
library(egg)
ggarrange(plots = plt_list,
          ncol = 2,
          labels = c('A)', 'B)'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>